# jQuery: Using the right selector and method to change some text?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the text where it stands "2 days ago", by using jQuery.

**html:**

```
   <div id="post_id_136_row" class="post_row row">
        <div id="post_id_136" class="post_column col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="inner_post_row row">
                <div id="thumbnail_column" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
                <div class="title col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                    <span id="post_title"></span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span id="time_added">
                        2 days ago 
                        <a id="edit_post_136" class="edit_post" href="#"></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery: (I have tried this, but it does not work)**

```
$('.post_row div div div span')[1].replaceWith('4 days ago'));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure of if you want "time_added" to be an ID or a class (class if you are having more than one row, which I assume you are).

If it is your only one, then use the ID itself:

```
$('#time_added').html('4 days ago');
```

Otherwise, you can use `find()`:

```
$('.post_row').find('.time_added').html('4 days ago');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3eE7M/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice on `id` vs. `class`!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and advise.

```
$('.post_row span#time_added').text('4 days ago');
```

Answer (score 0):

First save a reference to the `a`, change the text, then append the a back to the span

```
var theSpan = $('.post_row div div div span');
var aLink = $(theSpan ).find('a');
$(theSpan).text('4 days ago');
$(theSpan).append(aLink);
```